# What to do if there's a field the values of which should have different types?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design

I have let's say an application in which users can "create" animals. An animal can have different attributes: their color, weight, whether they are wild, etc. When I define in the DB what values an attribute can have, I have a problem:

```
Table: attributes
+-------------+
| id | name   |
+-------------+
|  1 | color  |
|  2 | weight |
|  3 | wild   |
+-------------+

Table: values
+--------------------------------+
| att_id (fkey) | name (varchar) |
+--------------------------------+
|             1 | brown          | ok
|             1 | grey           | ok
|             1 | white          | ok
|             2 | 300            | <-- not good to put this in a varchar field
|             3 | yes            | <-- not good to put this in a varchar field
+--------------------------------+
```

How to solve this? Should I create two more tables for int and boolean values and set for each attribute in the `attributes` table in which `values` table the values for the given attribute should be looked up? Or what would be a proper design?

Comment: You've come across the [Entity Attribute Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) "pattern", which many regard as a bad idea. If you can model the attributes strongly (i.e.a  separate table per "type" of attribute, i.e. Color, Weight, and Wild), I would suggest doing so. EAV is quite common in flexible systems which allow users to 'extend' the number of properties on an entity, without the need to dynamically create tables.

Comment: You can also add a `type` classification to your attributes table (leaving the attribute values weakly typed), but then enforce your type system in code.

Comment: You can give the attribute table one column for each relevant data type and add check constraints to make sure that exactly one is not NULL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are three Postgres approaches:

- Have a `type` column and a separate column for each type (`value_date`, `value_string`, . . .).
- Use JSON/XML to store the value (although that might limit the types).
- Store the actual values in separate columns.

Often, this problem arises because you want to have a column with "distinct" information.  For instance, right now i am working on a data project bringing data together from different sources.  I want to represent source-level information in each row, but this differs by the source.  My solution?  I represent the data as a regular row with a `source_system_info` column.  That column contains a JSON representation of what I want to include from the source system.

Comment: I've considered the suggestions and decided it's time to put in some NoSQL. As for this particular case probably JSON would serve me the best. Thanks!